# How to use of plus/minus together in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a if loop where i need to check the condition.The loop is like this:

```
if(tht(1)==thf(1))
      S='Original Note';  
  display(S);
else
          S = 'Fake Note';  
         display(S);
end
```

Inside that if loop i want to place that ±. How can it can be done? For example like:

```
if(tht(10)==thf(10±5))
```

How this is possible?
how both the symbol of plus and minus can be used together in matlab?

Comment: `if (tht (10)==thf (10+5) || tht (10)==thf (10-5) )`

Comment: Cant it be used in just one situation both together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `±` has no meaning in MATLAB. You will need to use

```
if tht(10)==thf(10+5) || tht(10)==thf(10-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to have something similar to:

```
if(tht(10)==thf(10±5))
```

could be:

```
idx=10
idx_p=idx+5
idx_m=idx-5

if(sum(tht(idx)==thf([idx_m idx_p])))
   disp('verified')
else
   disp('not verified')
end
```

Hope this helps.